# Filter records using cache vs DB index?

Tags: java, performance, caching, indexing, rdbms

Some of the RDBMS tables have million of records and some have few thousands.  I am already caching those records in ehcache. Say I have million of customers already cached in
ehcache from DB table. Now  have to search/filter customers on multiple attributes which is decided at run time

1. One approach is apply filtering on cached data. Good thing is here i can save IO calls which are costly Bad thing is I  need to do filtering in application(java)
2. Second approach is  fetch the data from DB using DB index.  Good thing is i can use DB index which will eliminate scanning through all records . Bad thing is i need to make
   IO calls.

Which is better approach performance wise ?

Answer (score 0):

> One approach is apply filtering on cached data. Good thing is here i can save IO calls which are costly Bad thing is I need to do filtering in application(java)

You cannot be sure that your cache contains all data, and that it is consistent. Making your cache is in sync with the database, possibly honoring transactions, leads you to many other problems.

If we are talking about a read-only, analytical and data fits complete in memory, you can load everything into the appropriate data structures (HashMap, Tree, etc.). Then you don't need a cache.

Filtering on cached data, typically means sequential scan through the data. This might be not very fast. Some caches provide indexing, but then you are locked in to very vendor specific extensions.

> Second approach is fetch the data from DB using DB index. Good thing is i can use DB index which will eliminate scanning through all records . Bad thing is i need to make IO calls.

If all your data is not in the cache, you need to do a DB request anyways and the DB needs to do the index access anyway, too. A database query can just return IDs so you can save the redundant transfer of the row data. Consistency may be an issue here.

> Which is better approach performance wise?

Also keep in mind that there is also your personal performance as programmer. Making to complex solutions will not make you happy and look good in the long run.

What you need to do depends on the cost of database I/O and your problem domain.

Comment: well when you say `If we are talking about a read-only, analytical and data fits complete in memory, you can load everything into the appropriate data structures (HashMap, Tree, etc.). Then you don't need a cache` lookup time will be fast but each time user needs data, he needs to make DB call .To avoid that we need cache

Comment: As written, everything will be preloaded into a HashMap. A HashMap is simpler and faster then any cache.